# Setting A Column to the 100th dec in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, decimal

I have a variance report query here I need the 'Variance' to not have 10 decimal points in the Variance Column. What is the most convenient way to round Variance results to the 100th?

```
WITH A AS
(
select
A.FACTORY,
A.JOB_NUMBER,
A.PROCESS_STAGE,
A.PART_CODE,
B.PART_DESC_1,
A.INPUT_QTY_STD,
A.QUANTITY_INPUT,
A.QUANTITY_OUTSTANDING,
A.INPUT_QTY_ACTUAL,
(A.QUANTITY_OUTSTANDING*100/NULLIF(A.INPUT_QTY_STD,0)) as variance,
A.ACTUAL_CLOSE_DATE

from 
(select * from [man_prod].[dbo].[JOB_STAGE_LINES]
 where JOB_NUMBER in (select JOB_NUMBER from JOB_OUTPUTS where 
 BF_QTY_ACTUAL<>0 
 and ABS(DATEDIFF(HOUR,ACTUAL_CLOSE_DATE,GETDATE())) < 12 and  STATUS_FLAG='C'
 )) A 
 join fin_prod.dbo.PRODUCT_MASTER B 
 ON A.PART_CODE=B.PART_CODE
 WHERE 
 A.INPUT_QTY_STD<>0 and 
 A.QUANTITY_OUTSTANDING <>0
)

 SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.variance >10.000000 OR A.variance <-10
 order by PROCESS_STAGE asc ,PART_CODE asc, variance desc ;
```

The Variance column comes out at 00.0000000000   i need it to display 00.000 or 00.000000

Help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use the MySQL [`ROUND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) function, the second argument is the number of decimal places if it is positive.

```
ROUND((A.QUANTITY_OUTSTANDING*100/NULLIF(A.INPUT_QTY_STD,0)), 3) as variance,
```

In this example if the value is `0.0000000000` it would be rounded to 3 decimal places, or `0.000`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[TRUNCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate)** option:

```
TRUNCATE((A.QUANTITY_OUTSTANDING*100/NULLIF(A.INPUT_QTY_STD,0)), 3) as variance,
```

or use the ROUND if you are looking for rounding(as suggested by doublesharp)

```
ROUND((A.QUANTITY_OUTSTANDING*100/NULLIF(A.INPUT_QTY_STD,0)), 3) as variance,
```

Comment: The question asks for rounding not truncation.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to convert it to a decimal of the desired length is what i prefer when i am not actually rounding the value, just formatting.

```
 CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,3),10000)
```

Comment: Where would this be placed in the query to effect the variance format?

Comment: CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,3), A.variance) FROM A WHERE A.variance >10.000000 OR A.variance <-10